# Can I develop online at Azure without installing anything locally?

Tags: azure

I think I misunderstood the whole Azure development concept. I thought I could run the Visual Studio IDE within Internet Explorer or something along those lines.

Comment: no, can't do that. Azure is a big bunch of servers with a a lot of nice wrappers/management portals. You need software to deploy before it hits Azure. And there is no such thing as Visual Studio inside of IE.

Comment: @trailmax [Visual Studio Online - Monaco](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/11/13/visual-studio-2013-launch-announcing-visual-studio-online.aspx)

Comment: @Win wow, that's very new!

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you'll use an RDP client (like mstsc.exe) instead of internet explorer. You can create a Virtual Machine in Azure that has visual studio installed on it and develop on that VM. There are a number of images already in the platform that support this scenario if you're an MSDN subscriber, I believe.

Even if you're not an MSDN subscriber, you can create a VM and set it up for development yourself. Then you can use your remote desktop client to log into that machine from anywhere and develop on it instead of your local box. This isn't limited to a Window dev env't either, of course.

I use this in scenarios where I have a constrained laptop but good connectivity and a desire to get some work done. You could use this to develop with a full IDE from a Surface RT, e.g. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I think I misunderstanded the whole Azure development concept, I
>   thought I could run Visual Studio IDE within Internet Explorer or
>   something

Azure is a web hosting environment in a nutshell. I think you are talking about **Visual Studio Online** in which you can run VS IDE inside browser.

Once you finish writing code in Visual Studio Online, you can deploy it to Azure.

[Visual-Studio-Online-Monaco](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Online-Monaco/First-Steps)

[channel9 - Visual Studio Online Monaco](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Online-Monaco)